# WPF Tree view, how to change indention

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, .net-4.5

My Treeview basically has "folder" nodes, and one level below items which do NOT contain other items.

Therefor the space for the expand / collapse icons is not required (on level 2). Can I give up this icon space and hence reduce the indention. The items (in the example "airports") shall be shifted some pixels to the left.

[image: Example tree view]

Important: Basically looking for the code solution (C#), not the XAML version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Really what you want to do is edit the HierarchicalDataTemplate and change the way it behaves.  The following page, has a pretty good high level view of editing the [Hierarchical Data Template](https://web.archive.org/web/20200107231925/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/davids/2009/06/04/hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-treeview/).

I have also found [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314052139/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) to be pretty good to start out with.  While neither of the pages specifically say what to do, you are essentially changing the layout properties in the items presenter.

## Edit

Whoops, I was incorrect.  Not HierarchicalDataTemplate, but TreeViewItem template.

See below for an example.  This is just the simplest way to do it if you KNOW that there are not going to be any third level nodes.

Pay special attention to the ItemsPresenter element named ItemsHost.  It has a margin of -12,0,0,0.  That means that its left margin is negative and thus spills out of the grid column containing it in the left direction.  Thus all of the child nodes will be pulled to the left a little.  If you have third level nodes in the future, they also will be pulled to the left.  If you don't want that, then you will have to supply different templates for different levels of nodes.  But that is outside the scope of this answer.

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Just a small reminder, both links provided in the answer are not valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```xml
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAirport}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-15,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```