# WPF treeview needed without indentation

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am very new to WPF and developing first form in WPF as I have some specific design and feature requirement in tree-view.

I need to develop a treeview where only root nodes should be indented as default while their treeviewitems should be start from same 0 position, no indentation needed.

Please refer below image for reference -

[image: Reference Image]

Kindly help me to get it done by sharing any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Either use Grouping with datagrid it will give somewhat following output:
[image]

Or can use RadTreeListView like control. More details can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreelistview/radtreeliestview-getting-started).

As per comment if you have to use the treeview only then you have to override the templates. You can refer the following post:

[Decrease indentation in TreeViewItem for deepest node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599087/decrease-indentation-in-treeviewitem-for-deepest-node)

[WPF Tree view, how to change indention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649183/wpf-tree-view-how-to-change-indention)

Comment: Thanks Mohit for response, I have to use treeview only that is my limitation, can you please help me out with solution for same.

Comment: I appreciate your support but my requirement is something else,  the links you have shared I already viewed earlier and review again once you shared, but using their technique they only remove space of expand collapse icon while my need to remove whole indenting and make all nodes at any level on same position i.e 0 where main parent starts. Can you please help me out for that. Thanks